# Unable to call method in Swift class that throws and has non-void return from Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, exception

I want to have a function in Swift that returns a `Bool` but that can also `throw` if an exception occurs.

For example:

```
 func doSomething(value: Int) throws -> Bool {
    if (value > 0) {
        return true
    } else if (value == 0) {
        throw NSError(domain: "SwiftClass", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
    return false
}
```

This works fine, from Swift, but if I try and use this function from Objective-C, the compiler can't find the method.  I know that the `throws` requires the Objective-C function signature to change to `doSomething:x error:&error` and this works, if I change the return type to `Void` -

```
func doSomething(value: Int) throws -> Void {
    if (value == 0) {
         throw NSError(domain: "SwiftClass", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    } else if (value < 0) {
        throw NSError(domain: "SwiftClass", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

But this has different semantics.  In the first example, I only need to deal with the exception (or non-nil `NSError`) if there is a problem.  With this code I have to catch the exception (or examine the error) and determine if it is a real problem or just the valid, "false" case.

Is it really not possible to use a Swift function with a non-void return that throws in an Objective-C context?

Comment: Hmm, can you add a `return` after the `throw` in the first example?  In Swift, if a method throws, it doesn't return anything.  In Objective-C, setting the error parameter doesn't get you out of returning a valid value.

Comment: I did that (and updated the question to relect the change).  No difference

Comment: That macro affects the visibility of Objective-C methods to Swift.  This is the reverse; Making Swift methods visible to Objective-C.  The `doSomething` method is simply missing from the `-Swift.h` file if it has a non-void return

Comment: I was just looking through [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) and it seems very strange.  For starters, they indicate that *if* the Swift method returns `void`, the Objective-C method will return `BOOL` (as well as adding the error param) (which makes only so much sense to me).  But nothing clearly indicates whether or not we should expect it to work when there's a non-void return.

Comment: And without it clearly specifying it should not work for non-void returns, I don't know how we're supposed to assume it doesn't except by trying it and finding out it does not.

Comment: Aha!  Adding `@objc` to the function declaration gave me more information - an error - "Throwing method cannot be marked @objc because it returns a value of type 'Bool'; return 'Void' or a type that bridges to an Objective-C class".  Changing the return type to `NSNumber` lets me call the function from Objective-C, which is strange because I thought that Swift automatically boxed Bools into NSNumber when required.  If the method doesn't throw it happily returns a Boolean to Objective-C

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in my comments, I'm unclear as to *why* this shouldn't work.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) doesn't give anything to suggest this shouldn't work, but it also doesn't explicitly state that it should.  My reading of the documentation says that it should work.

With that said, we *could* wrap this in a method that is callable from Objective-C by changing the return type to `Void` and using an `inout` parameter for the result:

```
func doSomething(value: Int) throws -> Bool {
    if (value > 0) {
        return true
    } else if (value < 0) {
        return false
    } else {
        throw NSError(domain: "SwiftClass", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

func doSomething(value: Int, inout result: Bool) throws {
    do {
        result = try doSomething(value)
    } catch let error {
        // If need be, assign some default value to result.
        throw error
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as per your comment, it seems the compiler would be happy if we returned a value that can bridge to an Objective-C class (which apparently doesn't include `Bool`), so we could wrap it as such:

```
@objc func doSomething(value: Int) throws -> NSNumber {
    do {
        return try doSomething(value)
    } catch let error {
        throw error
    }
}
```

And in playing around with this, it became clear *why* this only works when we're returning a value that can map to an Objective-C class.

The compiler will not let you return an optional from a method marked with `@objc` and `throws`.  Why?  Because while on the Swift side, we use `try` semantics to call the method, the approach is entirely different in Objective-C.  `nil` is used to indicate failure.

So trying to create a method with *this* signature in Swift:

```
@objc func doSomething(value: Int) throws -> NSNumber?
```

Generates this warning:

> Throwing method cannot be marked @objc because it returns a value of optional type 'NSNumber?'; 'nil' indicates failure to Objective-C

---

In the end though, I do still very much recommend that you write the Swift method as having the signature returning `Bool` and write a wrapper method returning `NSNumber` so that we still have our Swift method with the most accurate type possible.

Also, if you notice, `Bool` *can* happily automatically box up into `NSNumber`.  My wrapper method was written as returning type `NSNumber`, but the method I'm wrapping returns type `Bool`, yet Swift was perfectly happy to return `Bool` from a method that is supposed to return `NSNumber`.  The trouble most likely is that by default, if unspecified, Swift's `Bool` translates into Objective-C's `BOOL`, which is a non-class.

Objective-C wouldn't be able to distinguish between the three possible cases if your return type is `BOOL`.  It only has two possible returns from a `BOOL` method: `YES` or `NO`.  With `Bool` mapped to an `NSNumber`, it can return `@YES`, `@NO`, and `nil`.

And if it's me, `NSNumber` isn't really type strict enough for me.  I might be encouraged to write my own wrapped class for this.

```
@objc class BooleanObject: NSObject, BooleanType {
    let boolValue: Bool

    init(_ boolValue: Bool) {
        self.boolValue = boolValue
    }
}
```

Note that the `BooleanType` protocol means that Swift would still be perfectly happy to use variables of this type as if they were a regular `Bool`.

```
let b = BooleanObject(true)

if b {
    // b's boolValue property is true
}
```